# rank of augumented matrix and rank of sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A_1,$ $A_2,$ $A_3,$ $A_4,$....$A_k$ are nonnegative definite $n\times n$ square matrices, then what can we say about $\text{rank}\,(A_1|A_2|A_3|....|A_k)$   and  $\text{rank}\,(A_1+A_2+A_3+...+A_k)?$  We know, in general we have $\text{rank}\,(A_1|A_2|A_3|....|A_k) \neq \text{rank}\,(A_1+A_2+A_3+...+A_k).$ But I am thinking that the nonnegative definiteness of all these matrices makes ranks of these two matrices are equal. But how to prove i am not getting.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to calculate the orthogonal complement of the two images and see that they are identical.
Let $A=\sum A_j$. We have
$$ x^T A x = \sum_j x^T A_j x $$
Your hypothesis is that each $x^T A_j x\geq 0$. Then $Ax=0$ iff each $A_j x=0$. So $z\in \ker A = \cap_j \ker A_j$ iff $z^T A_j=0$ (all j) which translates to $z$ being orthogonal to the image of $A$ iff $z$ is orthogonal to the image of your augmented matrix. Your two matrices therefore have identical images, whence identical ranks.

Comment: Dear friend, i am not able to understand why $ Ax=0$ iff $ A_{j} x=0?$

Comment: I suppose one way is clear. Now if $Ax=0$, then also $x^TA x=0$ and then $\sum_j x^T A_j x=0$. But each term in the sum is non-negative so each term must be zero: $x^T A_j x=0$ and then $A_j x=0$ since $A_j$ is non-negative definite.

Comment: "It suffices to calculate the kernel dimension of the transpose matrix". What i am not understanding here is which transpose matrix? why it is enough to calculate only kernel dimension? And finally where you have calculated kernel dimension?

Comment: Further if z being orthogonal to the image of the augumented matrix, then how can we get the required result?

Comment: You are right, at first I thought in terms of dimension but the proof simply shows that the two matrices have identical images (by showing that the kernels of the transpose matrices are the same). Recall that for a closed subspace: $V=(V^\perp)^\perp$.

Comment: so you mean to say, if we show the kernels are same, then the proof is done?

Comment: Yes, indeed. In general you have : $({\rm im} A)^\perp = \ker A^T$ and $\overline{{\rm im} A} = (\ker A^T)^\perp$